# API/Library for MIDI tune creation in C#?

Tags: c#, midi, audio-processing, javax.sound.midi

*Please be kind enough to not to say this as a silly question. 
Honestly asking after refering to several links on google.*

---

I am in need of a API which generates MIDI tone/tune in C#.
Currently I'm implementing a "**Basic Optical Music Recogntion and Interpreting Application**" without any OMR API (using my own algorithms).

So far the recogntition part is successfull. and the interpreting part is left. Where the identified notes need to be convert into a midi tune (file).

I have so far looked into midi-dot-net: [midi-dot-net](https://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/)

Can some one kindly suggest me a good API for MIDI creation.(above mentioned process)

Further, Does C# has its own API/Library for MIDI generation like in JAVA [javax.sound.midi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html)?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# (.NET) does not have a MIDI API. The only API available on Windows is the old Multi-Media library AFAIK.

Check out [MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com) that wraps this Windows API and makes it available to .NET (C#,VB.NET, etc.).

It provides a Factory object to create (pooled) note messages and includes reading and saving MIDI files.

If you have any questions post them in the discussion list on the codeplex project site.

Hope it helps,
Marc (Author of MIDI.NET)

Comment: obiwanjacobi : Marc. Thank you first of all. 

I have so far extracted the values as 4C4 4D4 etc, where is denotes Duration, Note, and Octave. Is this API has a ability of interpreting this notation to a tune directly?

Hirosh

Comment: No not directly. MIDI.NET is built on top of the MIDI protocol. See also: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midispec.htm. Midi is a real-time protocol that defines events. Note-On and Note-Off are such event. So you have to keep track of time and play these Note-On/Off events at the right time. For Sequencer support check out the C# MIDI Toolkit on CodeProject.com.

Comment: Marc, First of all thank you very much. I successfully managed to interact with your API and get my work done for the windows form application. As an enhancement, i decided to implement the same for the windows store app using a metro UI for windows 8. Then i faced an issue with importing the CannedBytes dll (API) files to the resources in Windows Store App solution. Do you have any idea about it? is it due to any incompatibility issue with Windows Store Apps?

Comment: To my knowledge WinRT (Win-8 Store Apps) does not support Midi.

Comment: thanks, if its so, do you have any suggestion on generating a piano tune in Windows RT? 

ps: I'm not a geek in the field. I'm still an undergraduate. therefore please don't think like without researching, i'm trying to take an answer from you.

Comment: @obiwanjacobi Is this library can run on MacOS? If yes please guide me how to build it.I need to detect note-on/note-off when my computer connect with the piano.

Comment: No, it uses native Windows APIs. I think you need to use PortMidi for Mac. Hope it helps.